# Get Javascript output in table format

Tags: javascript

I am very new to programming and need some help.

I have below javascript in which I am pulling data from excel, however I am unable to display the variable output in table format. Can someone please guide how I can display the Variable ("exData1") and ("exData2") in a table.

```
<script class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-2-0" type="text/javascript"> ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js'); var currentUser; var idData; var titleData; function init(){
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed)); }

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    document.getElementById('userLoginName').innerHTML = currentUser.get_loginName(); 
    document.getElementById('userTitle').innerHTML = currentUser.get_title(); 
    idirData = currentUser.get_loginName();
    titleData = currentUser.get_title(); }

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace()); }

function GetExcelData1(){
    var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    var excelFile = excel.Workbooks.Open("Usage.xlsx");
    var excelSheet = excelFile.Worksheets.Item(2);
    var column = 1;
    for (;;){
        var excelData = excelSheet.Cells(column,1).Value;
        if (idData.toLowerCase() == "id\\"+excelData.toLowerCase() || excelData == "") break;
        column++;
    }
    var excelData = excelSheet.Cells(column,3).Value;
    document.getElementById("exData1").innerHTML = excelData+"GB";
    excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
    excel.Quit();
    excel = null;
    idTmr = window.setInterval("Cleanup();",1); }



</script>
```

Comment: can someone please provide some guidance

Comment: show what you have in html.  What are extData1 and extData2 you seem to be assigning them one value from an Excel cell.  Also, are you trying to populate all columns from the Excel file or just one column, it is hard to know from your script.

Comment: I will add an example for you, see if you understand it and if it makes any sense to what you are trying to accomplish and I can modify it later if you have any questions, see my answer below

Comment: Can I do something like this<table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="exData1">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th id="exData1">​</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Excel</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function GetExcelData(){
      var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
      excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
      try
      {
        var excelFile1 = excel.Workbooks.Open("test1.xlsx");
        var excelFile2 = excel.Workbooks.Open("test2.xlsx");
        var excelSheet1 = excelFile1.Worksheets.Item(1);
        var excelSheet2 = excelFile2.Worksheets.Item(1);
        var column1 = 1;
        var column2 = 1;
        var r = 1;
        var tbl = document.getElementById("mytable");
        for (;;){
          var excelData1 = excelSheet1.Cells(column1,r).Value;
          var excelData2 = excelSheet2.Cells(column2,r).Value;
          if (excelData1 == undefined || excelData2 == undefined) break;
          if (excelData1 == "" || excelData2 == "") break;
          r++;

          var row = tbl.insertRow();       // this creates a row
          var cell1 = row.insertCell();    // this creates cell1 in the row
          var cell2 = row.insertCell();    // this creates cell2 in the row
          var cell3 = row.insertCell();    // this creates cell3 in the row, for the sum of cell1 + cell2
          cell1.innerHTML = "<p>"+excelData1+"</p>";
          cell2.innerHTML = "<p>"+excelData2+"</p>";
          cell3.innerHTML = "<p>"+excelData1+" "+excelData2+"</p>";
       }
     }
     catch(ex)
     {
       alert("Error load Excel files"+ ex.message);
     }
     excel.Quit();
     excel = null;
    }

  </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div>
       <table id='mytable' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='3'>
       </table>
       <input type="button" onclick="GetExcelData()" />
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It does makes sense. But when I try to add it in my script, no table is created. 
I am editing in sharepoint webpart, using HTML source editor. Wish I had some traing

Comment: If I add simple html, it works. Having issues with table format
<div class="ms-rteStyle-Normal">
<span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-2-0">Current User: </span><span id="userTitle"></span> [<span id="userLoginName"></span>]</div>
<div class="ms-rteStyle-Normal"><p><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-2-0">Used Data: </span><a onclick="javascript:GetExcelData1();javascript:GetExcelData2();" href="#">Click</a></p>
<p><span id="exData1"></span>[<span id="exCost1"></span>]</p>
<p><span id="exData2"></span>[<span id="exCost2"></span>]</p></div>

Comment: Just make your html simple for now, so that you can understand what is going on.  see updated answer, but I think you are on the right track

Comment: Thank you. I am finally  able to display values in table.

Comment: Now I want to add two values together i.e exdata1+exdata2. Is it possible to have that in code as well?
How can take the result of two functions and add it in third function

Comment: since exdata1 and extdata2 are strings, then you can just add them extdata = extdata1 + extdata2;

Comment: This didn't work :(

function Total(GetExcelData1(),GetExcelData2()) {
        
  var exdata = document.getElementById("TotalCost");
  
  Totalcost = exCost1+ exCost2;
  
  
    }

Comment: you can not call a function like this, you need to add the Totalcost = exCost1+exCost2 in your for (;;) loop in the same function GetExcelData1().  Maybe I did understand you question, but all you doing is adding two values from two different columns correct

Comment: Yes, that's correct. i need to add two values from two column. How do I return excost1 from GetExcelData1() in here?
function Total(){
    var exdata = document.getElementById("TotalCost");

    exdata = GetExcelData1(), + GetExcelData2() ;

Comment: I just updated the answer were you can access both xlsx files from one function and loop through all of the rows, add value from one cell with another and populate the table with the values of cell1, cell2 and the sum of both cells.

Comment: Thanks Faljbour however the  the script didn'twork. All I get is button on page :(

Comment: sorry, I did not test the logic.  Yes there were a couple of issues that was causing the logic to throw exceptions, here an updated logic that works and I tested locally.  One thing, you need to have the full path to the excel files